# ubuntu (21.04) get's into loop when playing online video

Tags: video, crash, system

Sometimes when I watch videos from one site, they get stucked in short loop with video and sound but I can't do absolutely nothing except shutdown computer by holding power button. Any idea what could be happening? By nothing I really mean nothing including swaping to another terminal.

I was digging trough syslog for some more info, I hope it'll help... tho I'm not sure if there is real solution since of the log:

```
Sep  5 19:04:00 orange-NB named[1062]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
Sep  5 19:04:00 orange-NB named[1062]: network unreachable resolving './NS/IN': 2001:500:9f::42#53
Sep  5 19:04:00 orange-NB named[1062]: resolver priming query complete
Sep  5 19:04:42 orange-NB /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[2452]: (EE) client bug: timer event8 tap: scheduled expiry is in the past (-3436ms), your system is too slow
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB systemd-modules-load[287]: Inserted module 'lp'
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xea, date = 2021-01-05
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.11.0-31-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-009) (gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.36.1) #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 13:19:04 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.11.0-31.33-generic 5.11.22)
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-31-generic root=UUID=d7823b21-8e2b-498b-bf7b-a4e9125c5c23 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Sep  5 19:05:11 orange-NB kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai
```

included some messages around, network errors in this case can be ignored, I don't have IPv6, I gues problem is message at time Sep  5 19:04:42

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7,7Gi       2,5Gi       2,6Gi        43Mi       2,5Gi       4,8Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

```
$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

renamed from system lang:

```
$ swapon -s
File name           Type        Size        Used    Priority
/swapfile           file        2097148     0       -2
```

```
$ ls -al /var/crash 
total 12
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie 4096 zář  5 19:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root     4096 úno 14  2021 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 orange   whoopsie    0 zář  5 15:13 _opt_Qt_Tools_QtCreator_libexec_qtcreator_clangbackend.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie   37 zář  5 15:13 _opt_Qt_Tools_QtCreator_libexec_qtcreator_clangbackend.1000.uploaded
```

```
$ top
top - 22:07:08 up  3:02,  1 user,  load average: 1,14, 1,45, 1,60
Tasks: 278 total,   1 running, 277 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10,6 us,  7,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 82,1 id,  0,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   7839,5 total,   2615,2 free,   2636,9 used,   2587,4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048,0 total,   2048,0 free,      0,0 used.   4871,5 avail Mem 

... (running aplications)
```

Comment: I have no clue what's happening, my operating goes into loop or we could call it freeze and I can do nothing else than restart hardly computer. what else I should tell

Comment: just a little more info about it, I tried to look into logs, it could maybe have consequence with network error, it's last error before restart (at least I think... there are many logs with seconds of difference and than there is 1 minute lap between them and before it last error is something with network)

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s` and `ls -al /var/crash` and `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema you have it there

Answer (score 1):

Your /swapfile may be the problem. Let's increase it from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 8G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: ok, I'll do it in moment, but can't confirm if it help or not, since my problem occurs randomly, so for now I'll check it as solution and in case my computer do it some time in future, I'll let you know

Comment: works, thanks for help, tho I hope I won't never need to use so much swap

Comment: @orange Great news! Thanks for the update.

Comment: so some time passed and it happened again :/ I had only browser opened, maybe steam on background (+ sevices like apache, ssh and other...). But I'm sure problem is not with ram